# Ruby on Rails to_xml nil="True"

Tags: ruby, xml-nil, export-to-xml

I need your help on to_xml function. How can i make all nil="True" value to a default value '' (blank) when exporting to xml from active record.

Answer (score 3):

The `#to_xml` method Rails adds to `ActiveRecord`, `Array`, and `Hash` uses the `builder` gem by default. The XML is also passed through `ActiveSupport::XmlMini` where the addition of the `nil="true"` attribute is [hard coded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/890da5149df19c54124929ff8b533014b6b46e69/activesupport/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb#L119) to always be added for `nil` attributes.

You should probably look at [using `builder` directly](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) to build your XML if these values are problematic.

```
Builder::XmlMarkup.new.object{|xml| xml.value "" }
#=> "<object><value></value></object>"
```

You could also use other XML libraries. I only recommend `builder` because it is the rails default and likely already installed.

Another option is to convert the object into a `Hash` first (`object.attributes` works if `object` is an `ActiveRecord` instance). You can then convert any nils into blank strings.

```
data = object.attributes
data.each_pair{|col, val| data[col] = "" if val.nil? }
data.to_xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to set special default values for XML generation. This method can then be called from an overridden `to_xml` method which duplicates the record in memory, sets default values and finally generates the xml. Example code:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_xml_defaults
    blanks = self.attributes.find_all{|k,v| v.nil? }.map{|k,v| [k,''] }
    self.attributes = Hash[blanks]
  end

  alias_method :to_xml_no_defaults, :to_xml

  def to_xml(options = {}, &block)
    dup = self.dup
    dup.set_xml_defaults
    dup.to_xml_no_defaults
  end
end
```